# Imposing additional constraints leads to "Underconstrained problem" error in hitandrun package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to generate random points inside a polytope defined by inequality and equality constraints using the hitandrun package.

When I run the following code:

```
inequality_constraints = structure(c(-0.104167209201478, -0.416675347343698, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, -0.0625001953121682, -0.250003125025614, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.187501757824066, 
                               -0.750028125701647, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0791669800346426, -0.366673388971321, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0375000703133992, -0.200002000012319, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0.187501757824066, -0.562526367877581, 0, 0, -0.0541668133682833, 
                               -0.316671680608124, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0125000078132871, -0.150001125004565, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.750028125701647, 0.562526367877581, 
                               -0.0791669800346426, -0.366673388971321, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0625001953121682, 
                               -0.187502929713446, 0, 0, -0.162501320319279, -0.70002450056927, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0541668133682833, -0.316671680608124, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0.0375000703133992, -0.162501929698919, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0.162501320319279, -0.537523180249991, 0, 0, -0.029166709200581, 
                               -0.266670222252287, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0125000078132871, -0.137501117191277, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.70002450056927, 0.537523180249991, -0.0541668133682833, 
                               -0.316671680608124, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.250003125025614, 
                               0.187502929713446, -0.137500945316788, -0.650021125456988, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, -0.029166709200581, -0.266670222252287, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0.200002000012319, 0.162501929698919, 0, 0, 0.137500945316788, 
                               -0.5125201801402, 0, 0, -0.00416666753517347, -0.21666901390563, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.150001125004565, 0.137501117191277, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0.650021125456988, 0.5125201801402, 0, 0, 0.104167209201478, 
                               -0.312508138142221, 0, 0, -0.0375000703133992, -0.200002000012319, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, -0.162501320319279, -0.70002450056927, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0.0791669800346426, -0.287506408936679, 0, 0, -0.0125000078132871, 
                               -0.150001125004565, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.162501320319279, -0.537523180249991, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0541668133682833, -0.262504867239841, 0, 0, 0.0124999921881681, 
                               -0.100000500000533, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.70002450056927, 
                               0.537523180249991, 0, 0, 0.0791669800346426, -0.287506408936679, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0375000703133992, -0.162501929698919, 0, 0, -0.137500945316788, 
                               -0.650021125456988, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0541668133682833, -0.262504867239841, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0125000078132871, -0.137501117191277, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0.137500945316788, -0.5125201801402, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.029166709200581, 
                               -0.237503513051706, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0124999921881681, -0.112500492188701, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.650021125456988, 0.5125201801402, 0, 0, 0.0541668133682833, 
                               -0.262504867239841, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.200002000012319, 0.162501929698919, 
                               -0.112500632812953, -0.600018000359341, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.029166709200581, 
                               -0.237503513051706, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.150001125004565, 0.137501117191277, 
                               0, 0, 0.112500632812953, -0.487517367546388, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00416666753517347, 
                               -0.212502346370457, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.100000500000533, 0.112500492188701, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0.600018000359341, 0.487517367546388, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0.416675347343698, 0.312508138142221, -0.0125000078132871, -0.150001125004565, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, -0.137500945316788, -0.650021125456988, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.366673388971321, 0.287506408936679, 0.0124999921881681, 
                               -0.100000500000533, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.137500945316788, -0.5125201801402, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.316671680608124, 0.262504867239841, 0.0374999296873284, 
                               -0.0500001250002242, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.650021125456988, 
                               0.5125201801402, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.366673388971321, 0.287506408936679, 
                               0, 0, 0.0125000078132871, -0.137501117191277, 0, 0, -0.112500632812953, 
                               -0.600018000359341, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.316671680608124, 
                               0.262504867239841, 0, 0, -0.0124999921881681, -0.112500492188701, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0.112500632812953, -0.487517367546388, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0.266670222252287, 0.237503513051706, 0, 0, -0.0374999296873284, 
                               -0.0875000546875526, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.600018000359341, 0.487517367546388, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0.316671680608124, 0.262504867239841, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0.150001125004565, 0.137501117191277, -0.0875003828114131, -0.550015125278151, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.266670222252287, 0.237503513051706, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0.100000500000533, 0.112500492188701, 0, 0, 0.0875003828114131, 
                               -0.462514742466738, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.21666901390563, 0.212502346370457, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0500001250002242, 0.0875000546875526, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0.550015125278151, 0.462514742466738, 0.145832269970924, 0.0833329861125094, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0.104166124134281, 0.0833329861125094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                               -0.0625001953121682, -0.500012500207959, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.170831874140276, 
                               0.133332444449479, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.12916583246988, 0.133332444449479, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0625001953121682, -0.43751230489579, 0, 0, 
                               0.195831415810972, 0.183331652788183, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.154165478305003, 
                               0.183331652788183, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.500012500207959, 
                               0.43751230489579, 0.170831874140276, 0.133332444449479, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, -0.104166124134281, -0.0208331380217714, 0, 0, -0.0375000703133992, 
                               -0.450010125152403, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.195831415810972, 0.183331652788183, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.12916583246988, 0.00416661197959911, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0.0375000703133992, -0.412510054839004, 0, 0, 0.220830894984829, 
                               0.23333061113226, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.154165478305003, 0.0291661744831799, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.450010125152403, 0.412510054839004, 0.195831415810972, 
                               0.183331652788183, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0833329861125094, 
                               0.0208331380217714, -0.0125000078132871, -0.400008000107846, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0.220830894984829, 0.23333061113226, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, -0.133332444449479, -0.00416661197959911, 0, 0, 0.0125000078132871, 
                               -0.387507992294559, 0, 0, 0.24583031165821, 0.283329319483528, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.183331652788183, -0.0291661744831799, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0.400008000107846, 0.387507992294559, 0, 0, -0.145832269970924, 
                               -0.0624992838584149, 0, 0, 0.12916583246988, 0.133332444449479, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0375000703133992, -0.450010125152403, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, -0.170831874140276, -0.0374994296907971, 0, 0, 0.154165478305003, 
                               0.183331652788183, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0375000703133992, -0.412510054839004, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, -0.195831415810972, -0.0124997630227881, 0, 0, 0.17916506164147, 
                               0.23333061113226, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.450010125152403, 
                               0.412510054839004, 0, 0, -0.170831874140276, -0.0374994296907971, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, -0.12916583246988, 0.00416661197959911, 0, 0, -0.0125000078132871, 
                               -0.400008000107846, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.195831415810972, -0.0124997630227881, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, -0.154165478305003, 0.0291661744831799, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0.0125000078132871, -0.387507992294559, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.220830894984829, 
                               0.0124997161474312, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.17916506164147, 0.05416554949079, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.400008000107846, 0.387507992294559, 0, 0, 
                               -0.195831415810972, -0.0124997630227881, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.133332444449479, 
                               -0.00416661197959911, 0.0124999921881681, -0.350006125070649, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.220830894984829, 0.0124997161474312, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.183331652788183, -0.0291661744831799, 0, 0, 
                               -0.0124999921881681, -0.362506117258818, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.24583031165821, 
                               0.0374990078253177, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.23333061113226, -0.05416554949079, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0.350006125070649, 0.362506117258818, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                               -0.0833329861125094, 0.0624992838584149, 0.154165478305003, 0.183331652788183, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0125000078132871, -0.400008000107846, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.133332444449479, 0.0374994296907971, 0.17916506164147, 
                               0.23333061113226, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0125000078132871, -0.387507992294559, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.183331652788183, 0.0124997630227881, 0.204164582479279, 
                               0.283329319483528, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.400008000107846, 
                               0.387507992294559, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.133332444449479, 0.0374994296907971, 
                               0, 0, -0.154165478305003, 0.0291661744831799, 0, 0, 0.0124999921881681, 
                               -0.350006125070649, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.183331652788183, 
                               0.0124997630227881, 0, 0, -0.17916506164147, 0.05416554949079, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0124999921881681, -0.362506117258818, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, -0.23333061113226, -0.0124997161474312, 0, 0, -0.204164582479279, 
                               0.0791647370042483, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.350006125070649, 0.362506117258818, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, -0.183331652788183, 0.0124997630227881, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, -0.183331652788183, -0.0291661744831799, 0.0374999296873284, 
                               -0.300004500044452, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.23333061113226, 
                               -0.0124997161474312, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.23333061113226, -0.05416554949079, 
                               0, 0, -0.0374999296873284, -0.33750442973178, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, -0.283329319483528, -0.0374990078253177, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.283329319483528, 
                               -0.0791647370042483, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.300004500044452, 0.33750442973178
), .Dim = c(18L, 54L))
hitandrun_matrix = rbind(-diag(54),inequality_constraints,
                         c(rep(1,27),rep(0,27)),c(rep(0,27),rep(1,27)))
hitandrun_direction = c(rep("<=",72),rep("=",2))
hitandrun_rhs = c(rep(0,72),rep(1/2,2))
constraints = list(constr = hitandrun_matrix, dir= hitandrun_direction, rhs= hitandrun_rhs)
constraints = eliminateRedundant(constraints)

points = hitandrun(constr = constraints, n.samples=5,
                     thin.fn = function(n) { ceiling(log(n + 1)/4 * n^3) }, thin = NULL,
                     x0.randomize=TRUE, x0.method="slacklp", eliminate = FALSE)
```

I get the error

```
Error in findInteriorPoint(constr, homogeneous, randomize) : 
  Underconstrained problem
```

(the error appears when I run the last line). I am thinking that this may happen because the number of inequality constraints is lower than the number of variables (i.e. dimension of points to be produced), even though there are many equality constraints. The dimension of the points is 54, and after elimination of redundant constraints by `constraints = eliminateRedundant(constraints)` there are 20 equality constraints and 44 inequality constraints.

Initially, 2 equality and 72 inequality constraints are supplied in `constraints = list(constr = hitandrun_matrix, dir= hitandrun_direction, rhs= hitandrun_rhs)` so I tried to run the code without elimination of redundant constraints, that is skip the line `constraints = eliminateRedundant(constraints)` and instead run

```
constraints = list(constr = hitandrun_matrix, dir= hitandrun_direction, rhs= hitandrun_rhs)
points = hitandrun(constr = constraints, n.samples=5,
                     thin.fn = function(n) { ceiling(log(n + 1)/4 * n^3) }, thin = NULL,
                     x0.randomize=TRUE, x0.method="slacklp", eliminate = FALSE)
```

This then returns the following error:

```
Error in har(x0, constr, N = n.samples * thin, thin = thin, homogeneous = TRUE,  : 
  The starting point must be inside the region
```

I have also verified that if I omit the last two constraints from the matrix `inequality_constraints`, that is, I run

```
hitandrun_matrix = rbind(-diag(54),inequality_constraints[1:16,],
                         c(rep(1,27),rep(0,27)),c(rep(0,27),rep(1,27)))
hitandrun_direction = c(rep("<=",70),rep("=",2))
hitandrun_rhs = c(rep(0,70),rep(1/2,2))
constraints = list(constr = hitandrun_matrix, dir= hitandrun_direction, rhs= hitandrun_rhs)
constraints = eliminateRedundant(constraints)

points = hitandrun(constr = constraints, n.samples=5,
                     thin.fn = function(n) { ceiling(log(n + 1)/4 * n^3) }, thin = NULL,
                     x0.randomize=TRUE, x0.method="slacklp", eliminate = FALSE)
```

then the 2 equality and 70 inequality constraints that are supplied in `constraints = list(constr = hitandrun_matrix, dir= hitandrun_direction, rhs= hitandrun_rhs)` are reduced to 2 equality (the exact ones that are supplied) and 64 inequality constraints, and

```
points = hitandrun(constr = constraints, n.samples=5,
                     thin.fn = function(n) { ceiling(log(n + 1)/4 * n^3) }, thin = NULL,
                     x0.randomize=TRUE, x0.method="slacklp", eliminate = FALSE)
```

runs fine without any errors.

Any ideas on why the addition of the last two constraints results in an "Underconstrained problem"? Is this just a limitation of the package?
Or any ideas on how to generate the points without elimination of redundant constraints?

Comment: What is `APSD`?

Comment: Sorry for that; I fixed the question. APSD is equal to 27

Comment: When I ran the debugger on the code, it looks like it is failing because there are 44 variables and 53 rows by the time the constraints get to the function `findInteriorPoint()` and fails with `else if (m < n) { stop("Underconstrained problem")}` The 44/54 came from the function call to `transformConstraints()` which changed the constraints from what you had originally entered into the program. I will look through it some more, but I thought I'd let you know what I found so far.

Comment: When I use `x0.method = "vertices"` I get a different this error, `Error in findVertices(constr, homogeneous) : Failed to enumerate vertices. Is the polytope unbounded?` I thought I would check it out, since the error the function is currently failing for is tied to the `"slacklp"` method.

Comment: I also tried the vertices method at some point. The polytope is definitely not unbounded; the 54 non-negativity constraints and the last two equality constraints alone (without any of the inequality_constraints) bound the polytope inside [0,1/2]^54. The polytope should not be empty either; I have successfully solved an LP problem using lpSolve (i.e. status = 0, meaning success in the output of lp) under the set of constraints defining the polytope

Comment: Alright, I think this will be the last comment unless there is something else I can help with.  I pulled the functions myself and pulled out the function constraints for which your polytope is failing. It appears that it all comes down to when the package calls the function `lpcdd()` from the package `rcdd`. This solver won't allow more than 2 additional variables to the number of rows for this function. However, you could use `makeH()` and `scdd()`.  I did try this approach, but after running for an hour, I stopped the function.